# Convert Http Servlet Request to json to my defined object

Tags: java, json, http

I have a model class...

```
public class Incident implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Integer refNo;
    private String type;
    private Double lossAmt;
    private Date incidentDate;
    private Date incidentTime;
    private Date reportingDate;
}
```

FTL like...

```
     <form action="saveIncident.do" method="POST" >

        <input type="text" name="type" value="A">
        <input type="text" name="refNo" value="546">
        <input type="text" name="lossAmt" value="45000">
        <input type="text" name="incidentDate" value="10/05/2017">
        <input type="text" name="reportingDate" value="18/05/2017">

        <input type="submit" value="Save">
     </form>
```

I am trying to get Object From `HttpServletRequest request`

```
    Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();
    String formData = new Gson().toJson(map);
```

The above code returns as `formData` value `{"type":["A"],"lossAmt":["45000"],"incidentDate":["10/05/2017"],"reportingDate":["18/05/2017"],"refNo":[""]}`. Then I called ..

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").create();
    Incident incident = gson.fromJson(formData, Incident.class);
```

this throw `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException`
But, when I replaceAll the array symbols `[ & ]` using..

```
formData = formData.replaceAll("[\\[ \\]]", ""); // {"type":"A","lossAmt":"45000" ....
```

then works fine. Hence How can I convert to `Incident`object without replacing the Array Symbols ?

[image: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException]

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the problem is already at the point, where you parse the parameters,

```
Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();
String formData = new Gson().toJson(map);
```

as you see your parameters are arrays.

```
{"type":["A"], ... }
```

See the Gson won't convert an array into the scalar (simple variable) itself.

I'd try:

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
    parameterMap.forEach((key,value) -> { params.put(key, value[0]); });
```

for sake of simplification, here we are assuming non-null value and ignoring other (multiple) values if present. you should deal with it

Comment: Dear @gusto2 when there are multiple input will come with same name like `{"type":["A", "B"], ... }` then what happen ?

Comment: @M.A.Khomeni Then - how do plan to map multiple "id" elements to the Incident type? If you want to map json to an object, the json structure must represent the structure in the object type